# Need a Structure to maintain Data in Android

Tags: android, list, android-listview

I have a structure made from ListView - Customised as seen in Image Below [image: Custom List Stucture]

I can add New Products on Click of AddProduct Button 
A new Category gets added with EditText of Product and Quantity 
On that I have a (+) and (-) button which adds subcategory for Enter Dealer and Quantity with remove button on it .

The structure has been good .

But the data maintenance on it difficult . Like when I scroll , the focus gets lost and the data goes else where on ListView .

Kindly suggest some code for this .

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you to change the navigation structure.
You can keep the delete feature on the listView maybe implementing the swipe as it happens for example in GMail.
I would remove the add button and use FAB (Floating action Button) as Material guide lines suggest.
Hope it will help you!

Comment: Thanks for help . But I need help while entering text inside the EditText and maintain it while deleting , scrolling the listview

Comment: I think `add` and `delete` will working fine as you are saying. Its new style to use and also user friendly. But He is may be stuck with saving data of each `EditText` Dynamically.

Comment: @PratikButani : yep , you got me

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this thing with the following structure.

1. First of all I have created `Model` class for maintain data of `Product`.
2. I am saving data in `JSONArray` with collection of `JSONObject` of quantity added. (I have used JSON because I can save easily as a `String` in `Preference`.)
3. In `onCreate` of `Activity` I am creating `SparseArray` of Saved Products from `JSONArray`  like:

   ```
   try {

       JSONArray savedProdJSONArray = new JSONArray(productSharedPref.getString("productArray", new JSONArray().toString()));

       Log.i(TAG, "Saved ARRAY Count : " + productSharedPref.getInt("count", -1));

       for (int i = 0; i < savedProdJSONArray.length(); i++) {
           ProductItems tempPItems = new ProductItems();
           tempPItems.setProdId(savedProdJSONArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("prod_id"));
           tempPItems.setProdQty(savedProdJSONArray.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("qty"));
           tempPItems.setProdName(savedProdJSONArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
       }
   } catch (JSONException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       Log.e(TAG, "Json Err variant:"+e.getLocalizedMessage());
   }
   ```
4. Now in `getView()` of Adapter I am checking with current `ProductId` and Saved `ProductId` is matched. If it is then fill up `EditText` with saved data like:

   ```
       /** First check whether value of Saved product Array is >0 or not..*/
       ProductItems savedProdTemp = prodItemsSavedList.get(holder.prodId, null);

       if(savedProdTemp != null)
       {
           productQtyValue = savedProdTemp.getProdQty();
           holder.prodQtyView.setText(""+productQtyValue);
       } else {
           holder.prodQtyView.setText("");
       }
   ```
5. Here you also have to `addTextChangeListner` for `EditText` to save data in ArrayList and then you have to Convert in `JSONArray` when Activity is `Stop` or `Pause`

I think it is little bit confusing but I thought it is only helps you. I tried many times to find out solution but didn't better than this.

Hope it will help you.

Welcomes you if you have any question. (Sorry If you found English Mistake :D)

Comment: Should I save this in JSON Array while I type in EditText ,since the issue comes during scrolling , deleting of child item of listview

Comment: What you are getting on Scrolling or Deleting?

Comment: Its like the data on entering text in EditText in ListView , the data stays on scrolling down after leaving the screen and then scrolling down and coming back the data may or may not be found on same EditText , it might go to some other EditText

Comment: I think it is because of you are adding `EditText` dynamically

Comment: Yes I am adding it dynamically

Comment: I have heard its a known problem in android and I need a good waythrough for it